# C++11 unable to move class with unordered_map inside

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

In this example problematic line is declaration of `repo` member of `Basket`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Product {
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> description;
};

struct Basket {
    // this line is OK, just moves it
    std::vector<Product> ps;
    // Doesn't compile with this line uncommented ! Can't move map ?
    // std::unordered_map<std::string, Product> repo;
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    std::vector<Basket> baskets;
    Basket b1;
    baskets.push_back(std::move(b1));

    return 0;
}
```

When `repo` member declaration is uncommented, then i getting scary sheet of errors.
Tested on gcc 4.7.2 and Clang 3.3 and got same error:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Product'
... lot of similar stuff ...
```

Comment: implement a nothrow move in product as a sanity check?

Comment: @0x499602D2 does not if you uncomment the line OP asked to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a9e6eea733f59f1

Comment: This might be related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55043, although that bug is marked as fixed. If you change the sample code in PR55043 so that the unordered_map has mapped type std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> instead of just std::unique_ptr<int>, then it fails to compile with gcc 4.8.1. (But std::map compiles fine.)

Comment: Works with gcc 4.7.3 and 4.6.4 :)

Comment: and gcc 4.8.1, 4.9.0, clang++ 3.4

Comment: @chill: if you were referring to my comment, http://ideone.com/44RFGk is the code I had in mind (along with the error produced). Change unordered_map to map (in two places) and it compiles. Of course, it's not really related to gcc version; rather, to the version of libstdc++.

Comment: @rici, No, I meant the OP original code. Of course, gcc and libstdc++ are developed and released together and carry the same version number :)

Comment: @chill: ah. Try `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Product>> repo;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unimplemented feature in your libstdc++.

I checked my GCC 4.7.2's headers, `unordered_map` doesn't even have move constructor/assignment operator. They might have backported it for 4.7.3, but either way you'll have to upgrade your compiler and/or your libstdc++ to get that line to compile.

With a recent enough libstdc++ it compiles just fine: http://goo.gl/16Vnrj

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it failed to compile. The error message is saying it try to make a copy of `Product`, which can't be done because it contain `unique_ptr`, a move-only class.

However add

```
Basket() = default;
Basket(Basket &&other) = default;
```

does make it work.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd73f6030f478e48)

Answer (score 0):

You're other option is to make Basket in place:

```
baskets.emplace_back() ;
```

Then the compiler won't try to do any copy or move.